# Docker on Windows 10 doesn't start

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v

I just installed Docker to my Windows 10 PC. But when I try to run Docker with the shortcut on my desktop I get an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Y2A.jpg).

When I checked Windows Features Hyper-V is enabled. I restarted my PC several times but no luck. 
There is no virtualization software on my PC like Virtualbox or VMware to conflict with the Docker service. What should I do?

Comment: No need to restart Windows, just start the Hyper-V service. Restarting Windows isn't going to start the Hyper-V service if it's set to Manual or Disabled. This has nothing to do with Docker.

Comment: Thanks man. When I started Hyper-V service manually Docker started just  fine.